# Google Chrome session running but not working in firefox

Tags: php, session

I'm having trouble creating sessions on some browsers except Chrome. What is the problem with the code I'm post on Javascript?

I tried the following solution, but it wasn't ...

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
session_start();
```

```
session_start();

function addKupon($mac){

    if (isset($_SESSION["kuponlar"])) {

        $kuponlar = $_SESSION["kuponlar"];
        $maclar = $kuponlar['maclar'];

    } else {
        $maclar = array();
    }

    $maclar[$mac->mac_uniq] = $mac;

    $total =1;
    $count =0;


    $summary['total'] = $total;
    $summary['count'] = $count;

    $_SESSION["kuponlar"] ["maclar"] = $maclar;
    $_SESSION["kuponlar"] ["summary"] = $summary;


}
```

Comment: where is your problem? have you get some error? _What is the problem with the code I'm post on Javascript_ what javascript?

Comment: Actually, I don't have a problem with my code. There is no session in Firefox. No problem with Google Chrome.. I can't see the data I created in Session with firefox.

Comment: I think you have to debug it , maybe tryng to var_dump your data or activate the errors for php